# Swift: no calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression

Tags: swift, string, try-catch

I'm trying process string and set "try"

```
var str = String()
do{
    let str = try self.processMyString(strToProcess)

}catch{

}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
no calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression
```

Any of you knows why of this error or how can I fix it?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Apparently `processMyString()` does not `throw`. Why do you call it with `try` ?

Answer (score 5):

If your function can cause errors, define it like this

```
func canThrowErrors() throws -> String
```

like found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

Then you can use the try like you did already.

Answer (score 4):

`processMyString` doesn't `throw`, so there's no reason for it to be a in a `do`/`catch` block.

Further more, you're declaring a local `let` constant named `str` that shadows the outer `var` variable named `str`, which you probably didn't intend.

Just do this:

```
let str = self.processMyString(strToProcess)
```